# Set login details

Tags: html, forms

I'm currently designing my first website for fun and I'm trying to use a login system.
So far I have managed to design a login system below is the HTML file.

```
    <body>
    <h2>Login Form (Coach only) </h2>
    <form action="database.php" method="post">
    <div class="container">
<label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
    
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
</label>
      </div>

      <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      </div>
    </form>
```

Currently, it will accept anything that is typed in. Can anyone help with how to set the username and password to one thing? Would it be using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

This is just the front end what you've done. Now you will have to create a `database.php` since you've used it as form action and also create a **database** to store the values.
in the `database.php` first **connect** it to database and then use **insert** query and then use **validations** to check if database values match with the entered values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a database that contains the username and password. I connect to the database using; $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','myloginname','mypassword','mydatabasename';   How do I use 'insert query'. Sorry I'm very new to this.

Comment: insert query you put in the `database.php` file. You already have the `$conn`, create a insert query to insert the username and password and in `mysqli_query()` pass $conn and query as parameters.
For this you need a register form first to get the user data, insert it into database and then login comes in picture where you validate and let the person login to the dashboard